# Show all tags on custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, custom-taxonomy, tags, editor

I'm attempting to show _all tags on the editing screen on a custom post type (products). Adapting [these instructions](http://binfalse.de/2010/08/show-all-tags-in-wp-when-creating-new-post/)

I've created a simple plugin as follows:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_get-tagcloud', 'ajax_tag_cloud_wpse_99497', 1 );
function ajax_tag_cloud_wpse_99497(){

   $tags = get_terms( $taxonomy, array( 
   'number' => 999, 
   'orderby' => 'count', 
   'order' => 'DESC', 
   'taxonomy'  => 'Sizes',
   ) ); 
}
```

which doesn't work. On the custom post type, I'm still only seeing the latest / most popular 45 tags. Am I doing something wrong here? I'm completely stumped.

EDIT: Here's the entire plugin as I currently have it coded, and it still isn't working.

```
/*  
Plugin Name: Display All Tags
Description: When "Choose from the most used tags" is clicked, show all tags rather than most recent 45. 
Version: 1.0
Author: Michael Champlin
Author URI: http://mjchamplin.com
*/

add_action( 'wp_ajax_get-tagcloud', 'ajax_tag_cloud_wpse_99497', 1 );

function ajax_tag_cloud_wpse_99497() 
{

$tags = get_terms( 'sizes', array( 
    'number' => 999, 
    'orderby' => 'count', 
    'order' => 'DESC', 

) );

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed something like this for a client site, they wanted to add tags to all their products, but I didn't want them just making up new tags, I wanted to give them a list of tags to start with.

vancoder's answer provided the key I needed to get this done: the 'hide_empty' attribute.

What makes the code in the original question not work is it's incomplete. Because you are overriding a WP function, you need to replace the entire function with your custom version, which must handle all the functionality of the original. The original function is found in wp-admin/includes/ajax-actions.php (line 836 in version 4.3) so that is copied and modified to create the overriding function:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_get-tagcloud', 'ti_theme_tag_cloud', 1);

function ti_theme_tag_cloud() 
{

 if ( ! isset( $_POST['tax'] ) ) {
    wp_die( 0 );
 }

 $taxonomy = sanitize_key( $_POST['tax'] );
 $tax = get_taxonomy( $taxonomy );
 if ( ! $tax ) {
    wp_die( 0 );
 }

 if ( ! current_user_can( $tax->cap->assign_terms ) ) {
    wp_die( -1 );
 }

 $term_params = array( 'number' => 45, 'orderby' => 'count', 'order' => 'DESC' );
 switch ($taxonomy) {
  case 'product_tag':
    $term_params['hide_empty'] = false;
   break;
 }
 $tags = get_terms( $taxonomy, $term_params );


 if ( empty( $tags ) )
    wp_die( $tax->labels->not_found );

 if ( is_wp_error( $tags ) )
    wp_die( $tags->get_error_message() );

 foreach ( $tags as $key => $tag ) {
    $tags[ $key ]->link = '#';
    $tags[ $key ]->id = $tag->term_id;
 }

 // We need raw tag names here, so don't filter the output
 $return = wp_generate_tag_cloud( $tags, array('filter' => 0) );

 if ( empty($return) )
    wp_die( 0 );

 echo $return;

 wp_die();

}
```

This overriding function adds an opportunity to change the tag cloud configuration based on the incoming taxonomy without affecting other taxonomies.

As an added refinement, I changed one of the labels in the 'product_tag' taxonomy:

`'choose_from_most_used'      => 'Choose Tags',`

So that the user knows they are just getting a list of all the tags.

Answer (score 1):

By default, `get_terms` will only return those tags that have some posts attached to them already.

Try:

```
$tags = get_terms( 'sizes', array( 
   'number' => 999, 
   'orderby' => 'count', 
   'order' => 'DESC', 
   'hide_empty' => false,
   ) );
```

The `hide_empty` parameter will override this behaviour.

EDIT:
I removed the 'taxonomy' parameter for your args, as it is not valid: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms

EDIT:
I hard-coded your taxonomy name (which I'm hoping is all lower case).

Comment: This makes sense, thanks! Unfortunately it isn't working -- could it be because it's a custom taxonomy on a custom post type?

Comment: It shouldn't. I didn't read all of the article you cited, but I wouldn't trust the advice of anyone who recommends hacking WP core to be honest.

Comment: See my edit - this rogue param may have caused problems.

Comment: Saw that, and removed it -- still no dice.

Comment: Is the code you posted the entirety of your function? If so, where is $taxonomy defined?

Comment: Updated code in original question.

Comment: If your updated code doesn't work when you use hide_empty (which isn't included there), then I'm out of ideas.